# TextWatcher NullPointerException Failure

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext, textwatcher, addtextchangedlistener

I am working on an android application to list stocks using recyclerview and do some calculations with edittext. I have a problem I can not solve. Please help me.

***Note:*** *I know what NullPointerException is. I can run away from NullPointerException to use different ways but have to figure it out this to make the calculation process in the application.*

**Here is my Error:**

```
04-10 08:27:56.947 5198-5198/com.example.example E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.example, PID: 5198
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.example.model.adapter.StockAdapter$QuantityTextListener.afterTextChanged(StockAdapter.java:199)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7424)
        at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:9194)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:970)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:497)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
        at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:121)
        at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:5532)
        at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5343)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2640)
        at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7665)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1408)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1408)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1408)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1408)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1408)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1408)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1408)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1408)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1408)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2035)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1505)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2418)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1962)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3852)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3826)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3525)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3582)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3558)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3718)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2010)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1704)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1695)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:1987)
        at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Metho
```

**My EditText:**

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_pruduct_amount"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                android:background="#d7d7d7"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="start|center"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#116f57"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
```

**And my code in custom adapter:**

**onBindViewHolder:**

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00##");

        Stock currStock = mStocks.get(position);

        holder.edtProductAmount.setTag(currStock);
        if (currStock.getQuantity() != 0) {
            holder.edtProductAmount.setText(String.valueOf(currStock.getQuantity()));
        } else {
            holder.edtProductAmount.setText("");
        }
...

holder.edtProductAmount.addTextChangedListener(new QuantityTextListener(this, holder.edtProductAmount));
```

**Inner TextWatcher Class:**

```
    public class QuantityTextListener implements TextWatcher {

    private View view;

    private QuantityTextListener(StockAdapter stockAdapter, View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00##");
        String qtyString = s.toString().trim();

        CheckBox cbU1 = view.findViewById(R.id.cb_unit_one_product_name);
        CheckBox cbU2 = view.findViewById(R.id.cb_unit_two_product_name);
        CheckBox cbU3 = view.findViewById(R.id.cb_unit_three_product_name);
        CheckBox cbU4 = view.findViewById(R.id.cb_unit_four_product_name);

        Button btnAddToCart = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_to_cart);

        final int quantity = qtyString.equals("") ? 0 : Integer.valueOf(qtyString);
        Log.d("Quantity: ", String.valueOf(quantity));

        EditText qtyView = view.findViewById(R.id.edt_pruduct_amount);
        final Stock listedStock = (Stock) qtyView.getTag();

        if (listedStock.getQuantity() != quantity) {

            if (cbU1.isChecked()) {
                final Double u1TotalPrice = quantity * listedStock.getsUnit1Amount();
                listedStock.setQuantity(quantity);
                listedStock.setsUnit1TotalAmount(u1TotalPrice);
                TextView tvU1TotalPrice = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_unit_one_product_price_total);
                if (listedStock.getQuantity() != 0) {
                    tvU1TotalPrice.setText(df.format(listedStock.getsUnit1TotalAmount()) + "₺");
                    qtyView.setText(String.valueOf(listedStock.getQuantity()));
                    btnAddToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // add to paper
                            if (listedStock.getsId() != null || !listedStock.getsId().equals("")) {
                                Paper.book().write("ReturnStockId", listedStock.getsId());
                            }
                            if (listedStock.getsName() != null || !listedStock.getsName().equals("")) {
                                Paper.book().write("ReturnProductName", listedStock.getsName());
                            }
                            if (listedStock.getQuantity() > 0) {
                                Paper.book().write("ReturnProductQuantity", quantity);
                            }
                            if (listedStock.getsUnit1Amount() > 0) {
                                Paper.book().write("ReturnProductPrice", listedStock.getsUnit1Amount());
                            }
                            if (listedStock.getsUnit1TotalAmount() > 0) {
                                Paper.book().write("ReturnProductTotalPrice", u1TotalPrice);
                            }

                            Toast.makeText(mCtx, quantity + " " + listedStock.getsUnit1() + " " + listedStock.getsName() + " sepete eklendi.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    tvU1TotalPrice.setText("");
                    qtyView.setText("");
                    // delete from paper
                }
            }
            if (cbU2.isChecked()) {
                final Double u2TotalPrice = quantity * listedStock.getsUnit1Amount();
                listedStock.setQuantity(quantity);
                listedStock.setsUnit1TotalAmount(u2TotalPrice);
                TextView tvU2TotalPrice = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_unit_two_product_price_total);
                if (listedStock.getQuantity() != 0) {
                    tvU2TotalPrice.setText(df.format(listedStock.getsUnit1TotalAmount()) + "₺");
                    qtyView.setText(String.valueOf(listedStock.getQuantity()));
                    btnAddToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // add to paper
                            if (listedStock.getsId() != null || !listedStock.getsId().equals("")) {
                                Paper.book().write("ReturnStockId", listedStock.getsId());
                            }
                            if (listedStock.getsName() != null || !listedStock.getsName().equals("")) {
                                Paper.book().write("ReturnProductName", listedStock.getsName());
                            }
                            if (listedStock.getQuantity() > 0) {
                                Paper.book().write("ReturnProductQuantity", quantity);
                            }
                            if (listedStock.getsUnit2Amount() > 0) {
                                Paper.book().write("ReturnProductPrice", listedStock.getsUnit2Amount());
                            }
                            if (listedStock.getsUnit2TotalAmount() > 0) {
                                Paper.book().write("ReturnProductTotalPrice", u2TotalPrice);
                            }

                            Toast.makeText(mCtx, quantity + " " + listedStock.getsUnit2() + " " + listedStock.getsName() + " sepete eklendi.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    tvU2TotalPrice.setText("");
                    qtyView.setText("");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The error shows in this line(StockAdapter.java:342):**

```
if (cbU1.isChecked()) {...
```

Comment: Post your complete logcat

Comment: Where did you get findViewById of `edt_pruduct_amount` by assigning it to `edtProductAmount`?

Comment: I edited and shared my hole error